# date-fns formatISO to short format

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Is it possible to receive such date format using `date-fns`: `2020-09-21T21:55`?

If I try to use `formatISO`, it returns `2020-09-21T21:55:31+03:00` and I don't see any options to customize it.

Can be achieved by using `formatISO`?

Comment: Do the docs not help? https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need:

```js
import { format } from 'date-fns'

format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
```

Answer (score -3):

ParseISO is your solution, you retrieve the info from the server and then you can format() it since parseISO returns an object.

Comment: This tells us nothing at all